# R - How to let glmnet select lambda, while providing an alpha range in caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, glmnet

This question appears to have been asked before [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88756/r-how-to-let-glmnet-choose-lambda-range-when-using-caret) but was correctly closed as off-topic. I'm now experiencing the same issue and figured that stack overflow is a better place for this issue.

I want to use `glmnet`'s warm start for selecting lambda to speed up the model building process, but I want to keep using `tuneGrid` from caret in order to supply a large sequence of alpha's (glmnet's default alpha range is too narrow). the following attempt returns the error: `Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns alpha, lambda`

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) 
tuneGridb <- expand.grid(.alpha = seq(0, 1, 0.05))
model.caretb <- caret::train(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=train, method="glmnet", 
                           family = "binomial", trControl = fitControl, 
                           tuneGrid = tuneGridb, metric = "ROC")
```

How can I supply a range of values for alpha via caret whilst using the glmnet default lambda selection process?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the default grid search method for [glmnet model in caret](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/glmnet.R)

you will notice that if a grid search is specified, but without the actual grid, caret will provide alpha values with:

```
alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length = len)
```

while lambda values will be provided by the glmnet "warm start" at alpha = 0.5:

```
init <- glmnet::glmnet(Matrix::as.matrix(x), y,
                                     family = fam,
                                     nlambda = len+2,
                                     alpha = .5)

lambda <- unique(init$lambda)
                      lambda <- lambda[-c(1, length(lambda))]
                      lambda <- lambda[1:min(length(lambda), len)]
```

so if you do:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'cv',
                           number = 10,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           search = "grid") 

model.caret <- caret::train(Class~ .,
                            data = Sonar,
                            method="glmnet", 
                            family = "binomial",
                            trControl = fitControl, 
                            tuneLength  = 20,
                            metric = "ROC")
```

you will not get a grid of 20 combinations  but a grid of 400 combinations, for each alpha 20 lambda values:

```
nrow(model.caret$results)
#output 
400
```

I understand this is not exactly what you are after but it is pretty close without resorting to a custom train function.

To get closer to the desired result you can manually get the range of lambda values from glmnet for each desired alpha:

```
lambda <- unique(unlist(lapply(seq(0, 1, 0.05), function(x){
  init <- glmnet::glmnet(Matrix::as.matrix(Sonar[,1:60]), Sonar$Class,
                          family = "binomial",
                          nlambda = 100,
                          alpha = x)
  lambda <- c(min(init$lambda), max(init$lambda))
  }
  )))
```

create a grid of many lambda:

```
tuneGridb <- expand.grid(.alpha = seq(0, 1, 0.05),
                         .lambda = seq(min(lambda), max(lambda), length.out = 100))
```

caret is smart enough just to pass the lambda values to glmnet and not fit all the models

```
model.caret <- caret::train(Class~ .,
                            data = Sonar,
                            method="glmnet", 
                            family = "binomial",
                            trControl = fitControl, 
                            tuneGrid = tuneGridb,
                            metric = "ROC")

model.caret$bestTune
#output
  alpha       lambda
1     0 2.159367e-05
```

Ridge is the way to go in this case. Since this best lambda was in fact the lowest lambda tested

```
min(lambda)
#output
2.159367e-05
```

perhaps it would be wise to explore lower lambda values in the grid than glmnet "warm" start suggested.